# Finding first and last words of paragraph for custom language mode in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm trying to write a custom language mode in Codemirror. I started with "simple mode" (http://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html), but looks like I can't check for paragraph start or end (please correct me if I'm wrong). (A paragraph is defined just by having double break line before/after text).

So I switched to normal mode (http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi), but I'm really having trouble understanding hot the whole state machine system works.

I started trying to detect the first paragraph's word by defining a "blankLine" method and setting a "prevLineBlank" state variable there, and then in the "token" method I check for that variable, find the next blank space (or end of line) and return the appropiate style. This one seems to work.

Now, trying to find the paragraph's last word, I'm running in circles... I've managed to detect the last word of each line, and it works, but as said, I need to do the same only with the last word of the paragraph. Here's my code so far:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("netlang", function() {

  return {
    // This will detect empty lines to be used when detecting paragraph's first word
    blankLine: function(state){
      console.log( "netlang: BLANK line: ", state );
      state.prevLineBlank = true;
    }, 

    // Just initialise state object
    startState: function(){
      console.log( "netlang: start state");
      return {
        prevLineBlank: true
      };
    }, 

    token: function(stream, state) {
      console.log( "netlang: token ", stream );
      // Detect if we are starting a paragraph
      if( state.prevLineBlank ){
        // If we are, reset the variable since it is not a "start of paragraph" anymore
        state.prevLineBlank = false;
        // Find the next blank space
        var nextSpace = stream.string.indexOf(" ");
        // If found, move position there to style only the first word
        if( nextSpace > -1 ){
          stream.pos = nextSpace;
        // If not, it means there's only one word, so tak the whole line
        }else{
          stream.skipToEnd();
        }
        // Return the style name
        return "firstWord"
      }
      // If we're not at start of paragraph...
      else
      {
        var lastSpace = stream.string.lastIndexOf(" ");
        // No blank spaces, so only one word in line
        if( lastSpace == -1 )
        {
          stream.skipToEnd();
          return "lastWord";          
        }else{
          // Still not in last word...
          if( stream.pos < lastSpace ){
            stream.next();
            return null;
          }else{
            // Last word in line
            stream.skipToEnd();
            return "lastWord";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Any idea of how can this be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with CodeMirror's current mode system -- to know whether a line is the last line in a paragraph, you would have to look ahead to the next line, and that is not possible. See also https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/839

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Since you mentioned "current mode system", does it mean some other system is in the works that would help on this? Anyway, what options am I left with? Is there any workaround or hack I could apply?